# Format time to one digit

Tags: php, time

```
$value = 90;
echo gmdate("i:s", $value)."<br>";
```

the output is: 01:30

How do I format:

```
 1:30
```

Comment: @Jack This question is dealing with `gmdate` and has a second component, which does not make it an *exact* duplicate.

Comment: `gmdate()` or `date()` is the same thing; regardless, the referenced question covers the same grounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `i` character refers to minutes with leading zeros. You can use `intval` to remove the leading zeros:

```
echo intval(gmdate("i", $value)) . gmdate(":s", $value)  . "<br />";
```

Comment: @BandOfBrothers Not according to [this demo](http://codepad.org/ztUQJPM3).

Comment: I was searching for kinda of this answer for the last 3 hours and i am upvoting this. According to my needs it shows time perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

From the box of trickses:

```
$str = '01:30';

echo substr_replace($str, '', 0, min(1, strspn($str, '0')));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try gmdate("g:s",$value))  (or capital G for 24-hour format)

See all your formatting options: [PHP date formatting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: `g` refers to hour. OP is asking for `i` (minutes).